# Heroku Redirect from www to non www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, dnsimple

I've just set up my custom domain on Heroku. I would like to redirect from www to non www.

The Domain Names I have set on Heroku are:

```
example.herokuapp.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

I'm using DNSimple. I have the following settings (in the form Type / Name / Content):

```
ALIAS / example.com / example.herokuapp.com
CNAME / www.example.com / example.herokuapp.com
TXT / example.com / ALIAS for example.herokuapp.com
```

I've tried using a URL type record but it doesn't work. How should I do the redirect? Thanks.

Comment: all are correct except: `TXT` type(it isn't required), and explicitly setting the `example.herokuapp.com` in domain list of heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the CNAME on www.example.com and use the DNSimple [URL record](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirect/) to configure the redirect.